# How to know if a variable has been declared in Babel 6

Tags: babeljs

For example

```
var a = function() { };
var b = function() { 
  a(); // Identifier.name a - declared already
};
```

and

```
var b = function() { 
  a(); // Identifier.name a - NOT declared already
};
```

Here's the visitor

```
export default function ({types: t }) {
  return {
    visitor: {
      CallExpression: function (p) {
        var nameToCheckIfDeclared = p.node.callee.name;
        // ???
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of Babel's scope-related functions are on the `path.scope` object. In this case, you can check with `p.scope.hasBinding(p.node.callee.name)`.

Comment: Do you have any opinions about hasBinding returning true for `a(); var a = function(){};`? I mean, it's defined at the same level but the variable isn't available at the point it's used.

Comment: At that point you're getting more into static analysis territory, which isn't really covered by scoping. What you're doing is valid for `var` since it is declared, it just happens to be `undefined` but that _is_ considered an error for `let` because it is uninitialized. Babel does have some logic like this since which you can see here: https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping/src/tdz.js but it's not a public API and actually has lots of bugs still so definitely only use it as a reference.